# Replacing dynamic polymorphy with static polymorphy in C++

Tags: variadic-templates, c++17, stdtuple, static-polymorphism

Motivated due to the fact, that the avr-g++ places the vtables in RAM, I wrote a replacement using static polymorphy.

Consider the following example:

```
volatile uint8_t x;

struct IX {
    virtual void f() const = 0;
//    virtual ~IX() = default; // need delete
};

struct A : public IX {
    const uint8_t v = 0;
    void f() const override {
        x = v;
    }
};

struct B : public IX {
    const uint8_t v = 1;
    void f() const override {
        x = v;
    }
};

struct C : public IX {
    const uint8_t v = 2;
    void f() const override {
        x = v;
    }
};

volatile uint8_t index = 2;

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    const std::array<const IX*, 3> cc{&a, &b, &c};

    cc[index]->f();

    while(true) {}
}
```

Here we have some types `A`, `B` and `C` implementing an interface `IX` and placing pointers in the array `cc`. Then we call the virtual function `f()` for a specific instance. (Using this on a small µC like the AVRs, there is a "waste" of RAM, since the vtables are placed in RAM and each object contains a vptr, and a performance penalty due to the indirect call of `f()`.

So I looked for an alternative solution in this case: the simplest way is to use an heterogenous container like `std::tuple` and write a switch-statement:

```
const std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

auto f = [](const auto& v) {
    v.f();
};

switch (index) {
case 0:
    f(std::get<0>(t));
    break;
case 1:
    f(std::get<1>(t));
    break;
case 2:
    f(std::get<2>(t));
    break;
default:
    assert(false);
    break;
}
```

This yields to optimale machine-code but it is an unflexible solution. So I wrote a metafunction to call `f()` for a specific element of the tuple:

```
const std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

Meta::visitAt(t, index, [](const auto& v){v.f();});
```

And the implementation looks like:

```
namespace Meta {
    namespace detail {
        template<uint8_t  N>
        struct visit {
            template<typename T, typename F>
            static void at(T& tuple, uint8_t index, const F& f) {
                if (index == (N - 1)) {
                    f(std::get<N - 1>(tuple));
                }
                else {
                    visit<N - 1>::at(tuple, index, f);
                }
            }

        };
        template<>
        struct visit<0> {
            template<typename T, typename F>
            static void at(T&, uint8_t , const F&) {
                assert(false);
            }
        };

        template<typename T, typename F, size_t... I>
        void all(const T& tuple, const F& f, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
            (f(std::get<I>(tuple)), ...);
        }

    }
    template<typename... T, typename F>
    void visitAt(const std::tuple<T...>& tuple, uint8_t index, const F& f) {
        detail::visit<sizeof...(T)>::at(tuple, index, f);
    }
    template<typename... T, typename F>
    void visitAt(std::tuple<T...>& tuple, uint8_t index, const F& f) {
        detail::visit<sizeof...(T)>::at(tuple, index, f);
    }
    template<typename... T, typename F>
    void visit(const std::tuple<T...>& tuple, const F& f) {
        detail::all(tuple, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{});
    }
}
```

This works very well in my scenarios, yet is obviously limited to static containers (like `std::tuple`). There is also a for-each-like iteration `Meta::visit()`.

My question is: are there any other drawbacks / limitations with this approach?

Are there any improvements?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for CodeReview.SE

Comment: I don't want to cross-post: is there a way to move this to CodeReview?

Comment: not sure, but you can delete this question